# Can't understand what they're saying (listening)

Tags: listening

https://vocaroo.com/i/s1KAqThhtwgd
They're playing cat's cradle loudly and this exchange happens, but I can't understand what's being said after "少女らよ、もう少々静かにしてもらえまいか。"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おそらく「[尺取虫【しゃくとりむし】](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfttPgjSCoA)～！」「きゃー可愛いー！」だと思いますが、アニメなら絵と合わせて判断してください。

- [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/シャクトリムシ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A0%E3%82%B7)

Comment: おお～ほんとだ！　ぜんぜんわかんなかった…ｗｗ

Comment: なるほど～、アニメですが肝心な時に映らなかったです。